# How to create a WFS Layer in Openlayers 3 from MapServer Source

Tags: mapserver, openlayers-3

I haven't found an example of how to handle MapServer, specific Vectors via WFS in OpenLayers 3. If someone could provide an example, it would be much appreciated.

As example: This how i created a Vector Layer from a MapServer via WFS Request in Openlayers 2:

```
baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector( "test",
    {
        style: {fillColor: "green"},
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS(
        {
            version: "1.0.0",
            url: "http://localhost/cgi-bin/mapserv?map="+mapPath,
            featureType: "test",
        }),
            isBaseLayer: true,
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:31255")
        });

map.addLayer(baseLayer);
```

what would be the equivalent in OpenLayers 3?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial on OL3 and mapserver and see if it helps http://vipassanaandenvironmentalinformatics.blogspot.com/2013/06/web-gis-development-using-openlayers-3.html